# Battery impact of binding ChromeCustomTabs Service

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

What is the battery impact if ChromeCustomTabs Service is connected when App is in foreground and disconnected when app goes in background?

Is it ok to keep ChromeCustomTabs Service binded always?

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/guide-engagement-signals/